# Verification on "concurrent points", and a cubic discriminant

Tags: terminology, conic-sections, discriminant

It is well known that three lines are said to be *concurrent* precisely when they all meet at a point, namely the [*point of concurrency*](https://www.mathopenref.com/concurrent-lines.html).

In the paper [*On Sets Defining Few Ordinary Lines (v3)*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4714) by Green & Tao, they write (page 21):

> Finally, we give an example that lies on a cuspidal singular cubic curve, which after projective transform can be written as
>   $$
> \gamma := \big\{\,[x, y, z] : yz^{2} = x^{3}\,\big\}.
> $$
>   Removing the singular point at $[0, 1, 0]$, we may parameterise the smooth
>   points $\gamma^{\ast}$ of this curve by $\big\{\,[t, t^{3}, 1] : t \in \mathbb{R}\,\big\}$. One can compute after a brief determinant computation that **three distinct smooth points** $[t_{1}, t^{3}_{1}, 1]$, $[t_{2}, t^{3}_{2}, 1]$ and $[t_{3}, t^{3}_{3}, 1]$ on the curve **are concurrent** precisely when $t_{1} + t_{2} + t_{3} = 0$.

I have added bold text for emphasis.

#### Question 1

• What do they mean by *the three points are concurrent*? They have described three points as concurrent on multiple occasions, not just this one.

I understand that any projective point $[a, b, c]$ is an equivalence class and that it is a line, in some sense, but I imagine this is not what they mean.

#### Question 2

In addition, is the *discriminant* they mention related to the discriminants described in the [Conic sections of the Discriminant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Conic_sections)? If so, which discriminant do they reference? I have never used discriminants like this before, so I do not understand the sketched proof of their claim.

Comment: Concurrent points lie on the same point. They are the same point.

Comment: Discriminants, as you probably know them, only are a thing for 2d equations, usually of a quadratic form, but they can be generalized, and usually the discriminant being 0 implies some sort of redundancy or degeneracy of the equation. For example, if the discriminant of the quadratic formula is 0, then of course, there is only 1 root.

Comment: Looks like **concurrent** is a typo for **collinear**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Concurrent = Collinear

As Lord Shark the Unknown writes, they do mean to say *collinear* instead of *concurrent*.

Indeed, observe the following:

**Proposition.** Let
$$
\big[t_{1}, t_{1}^{3}, 1\big],\qquad \big[t_{2}, t_{2}^{3}, 1\big],\qquad \big[t_{3}, t_{3}^{3}, 1\big]
$$
be three distinct projective points. The points are collinear precisely when $t_{1} + t_{2} + t_{3} = 0$.

*Proof.* We may consider the affine points $P_{1} = \big(t_{1}, t_{1}^{3}\big), P_{2} = \big(t_{2}, t_{2}^{3}\big), P_{3} = \big(t_{3}, t_{3}^{3}\big)$ in place of the projective ones since each have a $Z$-coordinate of $1$. The points are collinear if and only if the line $L_{1}$ through $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ is the same as the line $L_{2}$ passing through $P_{2}$ and $P_{3}$. The gradient of $L_{1}$ is given by
$$
\frac{t_{2}^{3} - t_{1}^{3}}{t_{2} - t_{1}} = t_{2}^{2} + t_{2}t_{1} + t_{1}^{2}\,.
$$
Similarly, the gradient of $L_{2}$ is given by
$$
\frac{t_{3}^{3} - t_{12}^{3}}{t_{3} - t_{2}} = t_{3}^{2} + t_{3}t_{2} + t_{2}^{2}\,.
$$
The $y$-intercept of $L_{1}$ is
$$
t_{2}^{3} - \big(t_{2}^{2} + t_{2}t_{1} + t_{1}^{2}\big)t_{2} = -t_{1}t_{2}^{2} - t_{1}^{2}t_{2} = -t_{1}t_{2}\big(t_{1} + t_{2}\big).
$$
Similarly, the $y$-intercept of $L_{2}$ is
$$
t_{3}^{3} - \big(t_{3}^{2} + t_{3}t_{2} + t_{2}^{2}\big)t_{2} = -t_{2}t_{3}^{2} - t_{2}^{2}t_{3} = -t_{2}t_{3}\big(t_{2} + t_{3}\big).
$$
Now, the gradients of $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are equal if and only if
$$
t_{2}^{2} + t_{2}t_{1} + t_{1}^{2} = t_{3}^{2} + t_{3}t_{2} + t_{2}^{2}
$$
which rearranges to
$$
t_{1}(t_{1} + t_{2}) = t_{3}(t_{2} + t_{3}).
$$
The $y$-intercepts of $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are equal if and only if
$$
-t_{1}t_{2}\big(t_{1} + t_{2}\big) = -t_{2}t_{3}\big(t_{2} + t_{3}\big)
$$
which also rearranges to
$$
t_{1}(t_{1} + t_{2}) = t_{3}(t_{2} + t_{3}).
$$
The above equation rearranges to
$$
t_{1}t_{2} - t_{2}t_{3} = t_{3}^{2} - t_{1}^{2} \qquad\text{so that}\qquad t_{2}(t_{1} - t_{3}) = (t_{3} - t_{1})(t_{3} + t_{1}).
$$
By dividing out the $(t_{1} - t_{3})$ term we obtain
$$
t_{2} = -(t_{3} + t_{1})
$$
and the result follows.$\qquad\square$